# ASP.NET MVC Dynamic Design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I've recently started learning `ASP.NET Model View Controller (MVC)`.  It is very unique in the approach it takes for sites, I'm noticing the potential with `dynamics`.  Which will greatly improve maintenance.

But I can see how excessive use of `dynamics` could be bad, especially if you deviate from the `strongly typed model`.  So my question is this...

I'm creating a layout, but I'd like the layout to be `fluid`.  I want the design to be changeable very easy without impacting my logic.  I know you can create `Master Pages` and `Master Content Pages` which can hold a bulk of the layout for ease.  Except that will still have limitations for my use.

Is there a way to change these `Master Pages` and `Master Content Pages` into true dynamic entities? Essentially a `designer` could use a *What you see is what you get* field I create which allows the entire site to be modified?

My original thought was to store to create a `dynamic layout` where each `View` referenced a database; whatever those variables were would create the layout.  But I'm not sure that is the best approach?

Any suggestions or thoughts for the best approach?

Please I'm not looking to start a debate, but if people could point me into a direction where I can research that method of implementation would be greatly helpful.  That way I can find the best solution that will fit this projects need for a `dynamic layout`.

---

**Update:**

To give background on this project, my company has several subsidiaries.  Those subsidiaries will be utilizing the application but would like it tailored for there specific company.  To avoid excessive design layouts I'd like to `abstract` that portion.

That way my `logic` will not be impacted, but the software be module enough to meet all our subsidiaries design needs without me having to customize every single one of them or risk a designer affecting the `logic`.

Thank you for your assistance.

---

**Update:**

To help clarify, the goal is to allow the `User Interface` to be decoupled from the application.  In a normal `Windows Application` I would utilize `Inversion Of Control` to help segregate the interface and structure from the initial logic.

This decoupled approach is helpful, the goal is to decouple the interface in this case `Razor Syntax` which would design create the structure.  If you had a site:

```
<html>
  <div id="Page-Container">
    <div id="Header" />
    <div id="Content" />
    <div id="Footer" />
  </div>
</html>
```

That structure would be static, but in my case I'd like it to be `dynamic`.  That way my logic can be abstracted through the structure but the designer can manipulate and change the `page layout` however he'd like.

Comment: have a look at Orchard Project, where people can provide their own themes. It has a concept of Zones, which each theme can expose.

Comment: That sounds similar to Dot Net Nuke.  Where certain parts of the layout are broken down into Modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding your requirements exactly..... but perhaps the following premise would be of interest?

```
@model CompanyName.LayoutModel
<html>
    <body>
    @foreach(string view in Model.Views)
    {
        @Html.Partial(view);
    }
    </body>
</html>
```

This is going to be dependent on how whatever UI framework you using works though. The idea being that you present to Razor an object that just contains a collection of views which Razor then renders partially. In order.

Instead of using ASP.NET MVC for the initial serving you might want to examine sites like http://www.google.com/ig, they use ajax to read custom layouts for the users (if you edit your settings in the home page you can completely customise the layout and what kind of news you get on the home page) and then fill those layouts with data from further ajax calls.
To me this sounds more flexible, each of those AJAX calls can be to ASP.NET MVC methods (which return the output of razor pages) and the javascript can just insert the HTML straight into the DOM. This also gives you greater flexibility when calling methods that might take longer to execute or rely on 3rd party communication as it allows you to render "loading" animations and report errors more easily.

Comment: that is a great post, I'll check that out.

Comment: Its kind of annoying because now I'm looking for the functionality again..... I can't find it! Which is much sadness, it was very pretty. But the technical premise behind it still stands its just sad I can't show you the real deal. I believe Google News works in the same fashion but the editor is nowhere near as sexy.

Comment: If you do find it, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Oh wait I've found the original implementation that started this all off. Remember iGoogle? http://www.google.com/ig.

Comment: That's apparently what the bbc emulated but the users didn't really use it enough and it was confusing enough that they re-redesigned it a few years later.

Comment: Your answer is the closest to what I was seeking; hm.  I'll have to find some additional details on it.

Comment: Sorry, not specifically. If you want a relatively quick answer it might be worth asking via irc on the freenode server on the channels #jquery or #javascript. It'd probably be a chapter or chapters of a good jquery or javascript book.

Comment: Yeah im finding that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are looking for some kind of CMS. There are already a bunch of [CMS build for ASP.NET MVC](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=asp.net+mvc+cms&oq=asp.net+mvc+cms), however you may build your own that will fulfill all your needs by storing views in DB. In this case [this article](http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views) might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a CMS, some of the aspects perform like one but I'd like to avoid them.  Mostly because they are general rather then specific to the business. I know Umbraco is MVC, but do you know of any that aren't so broad?

Answer (score 0):

In razor you can easily do that.
You must have a model for your layout template and bind it in your razor layout.
Each part of layout can be in a `@if` razor block which checks fields of model and dynamically
creates each part.

Comment: Thank you for the post.  So use `Razor` to check the fields within a model so that it `dynamically generates` each individual aspect from within that model? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Just to be clear, what you want to do is generate the view dynamically for a controller action, rather than manually creating a razor template for each view?

Comment: What I would like to do is allow the `Razor Layout` to be altered dynamically.  I can't see `@ViewBag` being riddled throughout the code being beneficial.  But I'd like `Divs` to be able to be altered or added on the fly.  If it doesn't make sense I'll attempt to reword it better.

Comment: yes,you can see a completely dynamic layout in orchard project sources.